# Software installations without local admin rights

Tags: windows, privileged-account

In the light of fewer technicians to visit sites and install software on to PC's, users are requesting Local Admin rights to do it themselves.

Is there a safe way or procedure of doing this for users in a controlled manner?

Comment: Get help desk to remtoe desktop in/remote installation (MSI only)/third-party system management software that does software installation?

Answer (score 1):

Short story: it is possible and can be used safely for *advanced* users, but you must know that those user do have administrative rights on their machine from that point.

Now for the longer story:

Giving a local admin account to a user makes sense if he/she is aware of general security rules. Because once he has got it, the admin can no longer protect the machine from his errors. But I used that method as a non admin but professional manager for a laptop. I needed to be able to do *administrative* operations even in week-end when I could not be helped by my network administators, for example changing an IP address to connect my professional laptop on my personal internet access. Or to install a particular reader to display an important document.

The rule was:

- I informed the administrators of what I had done with the admin account
- my normal account had no admin privileges
- I only used the local admin account for short operations after thinking twice on what the risk was
- I was often having coffee with the system admins to be fully aware of all the security rules

If you fear that a user could install anything, giving him/her a local admin account is very near to opening Pandora's box: anything can happen beyond that point

TL/DR: while it can save time for both the admins and users, a local admin account should only be given to *security educated* people

As you were said in comment, if the need for administrative operations is only during normal working hours, and if the ratio user/admin is not too high, remote desktop from the admins can be a safer and simpler alternative...

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are looking for a Privilege Management solution. There are a variety of vendors that provide products in this space. I would not want to recommend one over any other. You would have to evaluate which is the best fit for your environment and needs. But a good place to start would be looking at what SANS has published for "Controlled Use of Administrative Privileges" at https://www.sans.org/critical-security-controls/vendor-solutions/control/5

Answer (score 0):

Local admin accounts for standard users are a bad idea.  It opens a slew of other problems to troubleshoot including conflicting software, unintentional changing of necessary settings, etc.  You're providing a larger surface to attack if you allow your users to be local admins to a box and creating more issues for updating / managing 3rd party software.